# Creating a custom installer for a java application

Tags: java, jar, installation, advanced-installer

I am writing a java application which behavior is related to a specific country, when the user installs the application he/she can choose a country, so the installed app will be matched to the chosen country.

In other words, the java application gets a value from the installer as an argument, and operates according to that value.
What is the best way to do that ?

I've downloaded [Advanced Installer](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/)
and created a ComboBox that contains the countries that user can choose.
I saw that i can hold the selected value from the ComboBox to a property called COMBO_VALUE.
But i didn't succeed to read it on java application.
how can i do that ? 
is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

A solution is to [save the value in the HKCU registry hive](http://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/tutorial-professional.html#registry), and have the app read it from there when it is launched.

The above linked examples shows how to save the install path, which is stored in the property APPDIR, but the same can be done for any other properties, like the one you are using for your combobox.